# Dynamic Jasper exportToHtml() function is not displaying images in html page

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am trying to export pie chart in html. when i call exportToHTML() then program is exporting it to html file,but it is not showing the images.

i viewed the page source of that generated html page then the src of image is null.

how to get my pie chart image in html page..
help me.

Comment: Do you have jrxml file or you generate report with DynamicJasper API?

Comment: @Alex K : i am having .jrxml file that is generated with the help of dynamicjasper API..when i am exporting to pdf pie is shown prperly but while exporting to html,images are not displayed..